# Sorted Word frequency count using python

Tags: python, sorting, word-frequency

I have to count the word frequency in a text using python. I thought of keeping words in a dictionary and having a count for each of these words.

Now if I have to sort the words according to # of occurrences. Can i do it with same dictionary instead of using a new dictionary which has the key as the count and array of words as the values ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: Sort a dictionary by value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/python-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)

Comment: Fun fact: a word's frequency is always roughly equal to 1 divided by it's rank. So, the 2nd most common word appears about 1/2 as often as the 1st place.  The 3rd appears 1/3 times, etc. The 333rd appears 1/333 times as often. This applies to all languages and nobody really knows why.  ([Zipf's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipf%27s_law))

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use the same dictionary:

```
>>> d = { "foo": 4, "bar": 2, "quux": 3 }
>>> sorted(d.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])
```

The second line prints:

```
[('bar', 2), ('quux', 3), ('foo', 4)]
```

If you only want a sorted word list, do:

```
>>> [pair[0] for pair in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])]
```

That line prints:

```
['bar', 'quux', 'foo']
```

Comment: what if the values, are equal? If the values are equal, is there a way to sort them in respect to their length instead?

Comment: Like if "bar" and "quux" have an equal count of 3, is there a way to make "quux" come before "bar"?

Comment: For the second option, you can just use `sorted(d.keys(), key=lambda item: d[item])`.

Answer (score 63):

**WARNING:** This example requires Python 2.7 or higher.

Python's built-in [`Counter`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) object is exactly what you're looking for. Counting words is even the first example in the documentation:

```
>>> # Tally occurrences of words in a list
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> cnt = Counter()
>>> for word in ['red', 'blue', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'blue']:
...     cnt[word] += 1
>>> cnt
Counter({'blue': 3, 'red': 2, 'green': 1})
```

As specified in the comments, `Counter` takes an iterable, so the above example is merely for illustration and is equivalent to:

```
>>> mywords = ['red', 'blue', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'blue']
>>> cnt = Counter(mywords)
>>> cnt
Counter({'blue': 3, 'red': 2, 'green': 1})
```

Comment: Beware, `Counter` is only supported in Python 2.7 and higher.

Comment: You might want to add `from collections import Counter` before all this :)

Comment: @Tim - Good idea (even though I just directly copied from the documentation).

Comment: It's more for illustration... and it's **from the Python documentation**! (I updated the example anyway.)

Comment: What about the sorting the words by their frequency of occurrence?

Comment: @martineu: Some other answers already covered it but here would be a one-liner for it:  `sorted(cnt.items(), key=lambda i: i[1])`

Comment: @martineu: you could call `cnt.most_common()` to sort by frequencies (in reverse)

Answer (score 6):

I have just wrote a similar program, with the help of Stack Overflow guys:

```
from string import punctuation
from operator import itemgetter

N = 100
words = {}

words_gen = (word.strip(punctuation).lower() for line in open("poi_run.txt")
                                             for word in line.split())

for word in words_gen:
    words[word] = words.get(word, 0) + 1

top_words = sorted(words.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[:N]

for word, frequency in top_words:
    print ("%s %d" % (word, frequency))
```

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> d = {'a': 3, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 5, 'e': 0}
>>> l = d.items()
>>> l.sort(key = lambda item: item[1])
>>> l
[('e', 0), ('b', 1), ('c', 2), ('a', 3), ('d', 5)]
```

Comment: This will have an extra list of tuples. So thats an extra datastructure right ?

Comment: Yes, the list is extra, but the tuples could be eliminated if you wanted only the word or the count. Also you would probably need to use a list after constructing that second dictionary anyways, so it is creating one less needed structure.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `Counter` *and* `defaultdict` in the Python 2.7 `collections` module in a two-step process. First use `Counter` to create a dictionary where each word is a key with the associated frequency count. This is fairly trivial.

Secondly `defaultdict` could be used to create an inverted or reversed dictionary where the keys are the frequency of occurrence and the associated values are lists of the word or words that were encountered that many times. Here's what I mean:

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

wordlist = ['red', 'yellow', 'blue', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'blue', 'yellow']

# invert a temporary Counter(wordlist) dictionary so keys are
# frequency of occurrence and values are lists the words encountered
freqword = defaultdict(list)
for word, freq in Counter(wordlist).items():
    freqword[freq].append(word)

# print in order of occurrence (with sorted list of words)
for freq in sorted(freqword):
    print('count {}: {}'.format(freq, sorted(freqword[freq])))
```

Output:

```
count 1: ['green']
count 2: ['red', 'yellow']
count 3: ['blue']
```

Answer (score 3):

To find the frequency of these items its easier then you guys are making it.  if you have all the words in a list (which is easy to do using the string split function).  Then:

```
#(Pseudo Python Code) 

listOfWords = inputString.split() # splits the words up from whitespace
setOfWords = Set(listOfWords) #  Gives you all the unique words (no duplicates)

for each word in setOfWords  #Count how many words are in the list
   print word + " appears: " + listOfWords.Count(word) + "times"
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are going to require additional text processing, it may be worth importing `nltk` (Natural Language Toolkit) into your project. Here's an example, using JFK's inauguration speech:

```
import nltk

speech_text = "Vice President Johnson, Mr. Speaker, Mr. Chief Justice, President Eisenhower, Vice President Nixon, President Truman, reverend clergy, fellow citizens: We observe today not a victory of party, but a celebration of freedom — symbolizing an end, as well as a beginning — signifying renewal, as well as change. For I have sworn before you and Almighty God the same solemn oath our forebears prescribed nearly a century and three-quarters ago. The world is very different now. For man holds in his mortal hands the power to abolish all forms of human poverty and all forms of human life. And yet the same revolutionary beliefs for which our forebears fought are still at issue around the globe — the belief that the rights of man come not from the generosity of the state, but from the hand of God. We dare not forget today that we are the heirs of that first revolution. Let the word go forth from this time and place, to friend and foe alike, that the torch has been passed to a new generation of Americans — born in this century, tempered by war, disciplined by a hard and bitter peace, proud of our ancient heritage, and unwilling to witness or permit the slow undoing of those human rights to which this nation has always been committed, and to which we are committed today at home and around the world. Let every nation know, whether it wishes us well or ill, that we shall pay any price, bear any burden, meet any hardship, support any friend, oppose any foe, to assure the survival and the success of liberty. This much we pledge — and more. To those old allies whose cultural and spiritual origins we share, we pledge the loyalty of faithful friends. United there is little we cannot do in a host of cooperative ventures. Divided there is little we can do — for we dare not meet a powerful challenge at odds and split asunder. To those new states whom we welcome to the ranks of the free, we pledge our word that one form of colonial control shall not have passed away merely to be replaced by a far more iron tyranny. We shall not always expect to find them supporting our view. But we shall always hope to find them strongly supporting their own freedom — and to remember that, in the past, those who foolishly sought power by riding the back of the tiger ended up inside. To those people in the huts and villages of half the globe struggling to break the bonds of mass misery, we pledge our best efforts to help them help themselves, for whatever period is required — not because the Communists may be doing it, not because we seek their votes, but because it is right. If a free society cannot help the many who are poor, it cannot save the few who are rich. To our sister republics south of our border, we offer a special pledge: to convert our good words into good deeds, in a new alliance for progress, to assist free men and free governments in casting off the chains of poverty. But this peaceful revolution of hope cannot become the prey of hostile powers. Let all our neighbors know that we shall join with them to oppose aggression or subversion anywhere in the Americas. And let every other power know that this hemisphere intends to remain the master of its own house. To that world assembly of sovereign states, the United Nations, our last best hope in an age where the instruments of war have far outpaced the instruments of peace, we renew our pledge of support — to prevent it from becoming merely a forum for invective, to strengthen its shield of the new and the weak, and to enlarge the area in which its writ may run. Finally, to those nations who would make themselves our adversary, we offer not a pledge but a request: that both sides begin anew the quest for peace, before the dark powers of destruction unleashed by science engulf all humanity in planned or accidental self-destruction. We dare not tempt them with weakness. For only when our arms are sufficient beyond doubt can we be certain beyond doubt that they will never be employed. But neither can two great and powerful groups of nations take comfort from our present course — both sides overburdened by the cost of modern weapons, both rightly alarmed by the steady spread of the deadly atom, yet both racing to alter that uncertain balance of terror that stays the hand of mankind’s final war. So let us begin anew — remembering on both sides that civility is not a sign of weakness, and sincerity is always subject to proof. Let us never negotiate out of fear, but let us never fear to negotiate. Let both sides explore what problems unite us instead of belaboring those problems which divide us. Let both sides, for the first time, formulate serious and precise proposals for the inspection and control of arms, and bring the absolute power to destroy other nations under the absolute control of all nations. Let both sides seek to invoke the wonders of science instead of its terrors. Together let us explore the stars, conquer the deserts, eradicate disease, tap the ocean depths, and encourage the arts and commerce. Let both sides unite to heed, in all corners of the earth, the command of Isaiah — to “undo the heavy burdens, and [to] let the oppressed go free.”¹ And, if a beachhead of cooperation may push back the jungle of suspicion, let both sides join in creating a new endeavor — not a new balance of power, but a new world of law — where the strong are just, and the weak secure, and the peace preserved. All this will not be finished in the first one hundred days. Nor will it be finished in the first one thousand days; nor in the life of this Administration; nor even perhaps in our lifetime on this planet. But let us begin. In your hands, my fellow citizens, more than mine, will rest the final success or failure of our course. Since this country was founded, each generation of Americans has been summoned to give testimony to its national loyalty. The graves of young Americans who answered the call to service surround the globe. Now the trumpet summons us again — not as a call to bear arms, though arms we need — not as a call to battle, though embattled we are — but a call to bear the burden of a long twilight struggle, year in and year out, “rejoicing in hope; patient in tribulation,”² a struggle against the common enemies of man: tyranny, poverty, disease, and war itself. Can we forge against these enemies a grand and global alliance, North and South, East and West, that can assure a more fruitful life for all mankind? Will you join in that historic effort? In the long history of the world, only a few generations have been granted the role of defending freedom in its hour of maximum danger. I do not shrink from this responsibility — I welcome it. I do not believe that any of us would exchange places with any other people or any other generation. The energy, the faith, the devotion which we bring to this endeavor will light our country and all who serve it. And the glow from that fire can truly light the world. And so, my fellow Americans, ask not what your country can do for you; ask what you can do for your country. My fellow citizens of the world, ask not what America will do for you, but what together we can do for the freedom of man. Finally, whether you are citizens of America or citizens of the world, ask of us here the same high standards of strength and sacrifice which we ask of you. With a good conscience our only sure reward, with history the final judge of our deeds, let us go forth to lead the land we love, asking His blessing and His help, but knowing that here on earth God’s work must truly be our own."

# Tokenize the words
all_words = speech_text.lower().split()

# Create a frequency distribution
freq = nltk.FreqDist(all_words)

# Show the top 10 words in the list, with counts
freq.items()[:10]

Out[5]: 
[('the', 86),
 ('of', 66),
 ('to', 42),
 ('and', 40),
 ('we', 30),
 ('a', 29),
 ('in', 24),
 ('our', 21),
 ('not', 19),
 ('that', 19)]

# Show the top 10 keys in the frequency dictionary
freq.keys()[:10]

Out[6]: ['the', 'of', 'to', 'and', 'we', 'a', 'in', 'our', 'not', 'that']

# Those frequent words aren't very interesting... let's strip common words
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
clean_words = [w for w in all_words if not w in stop_words]
freq_clean  = nltk.FreqDist(clean_words)

# This is a little more interesting
freq_clean.items()[1:10]
[('let', 16),
 ('us', 11),
 ('new', 7),
 ('sides', 7),
 ('pledge', 6),
 ('ask', 5),
 ('shall', 5),
 ('always', 4),
 ('call', 4)]
```

NLTK will allow you to do all manner of other interesting analysis with text, too, should the need arise. Here's a quick example of how you would find the top 10 bigrams that occur more than 3 times in the text:

```
bigram_measures = nltk.collocations.BigramAssocMeasures()
bigram_finder   = nltk.collocations.BigramCollocationFinder.from_words(all_words)
bigram_finder.apply_freq_filter(3)
bigram_finder.nbest(bigram_measures.pmi, 10)

Out[28]: 
[('my', 'fellow'),
 ('both', 'sides'),
 ('can', 'do'),
 ('dare', 'not'),
 ('let', 'us'),
 ('we', 'dare'),
 ('do', 'for'),
 ('let', 'both'),
 ('we', 'shall'),
 ('a', 'call')]
```

Refer to the [NLTK Documentation](http://nltk.org/) for more information and examples of how to, for instance, quickly create a plot of the most frequent terms in your text.

Answer (score 2):

Didn't know there was a `Counter` object for such a task. Here's how I did it back then, similar to your approach. You can do the sorting on a representation of the same dictionary.

```
#Takes a list and returns a descending sorted dict of words and their counts
def countWords(a_list):
    words = {}
    for i in range(len(a_list)):
        item = a_list[i]
        count = a_list.count(item)
        words[item] = count
    return sorted(words.items(), key = lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)
```

An example:

```
>>>countWords("the quick red fox jumped over the lazy brown dog".split())
[('the', 2), ('brown', 1), ('lazy', 1), ('jumped', 1), ('over', 1), ('fox', 1), ('dog', 1), ('quick', 1), ('red', 1)]
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a similar program few days ago. Program uses two arguments: filename (required) and N (optional)

```
from collections import Counter
import re
import sys

if sys.version_info <(2,7):
    Sys.exit("Must use Python 2.7 or greater")

if len(sys.argv)<2:
    sys.exit('Usage: python %s filename N'%sys.argv[0])

n=0
if len(sys.argv)>2:
    try:
        n=int(sys.argv[2])
        if n<=0:
            raise ValueError
    except ValueError:
        sys.exit("Invalid value for N: %s.\nN must be an integer greater than 0"%sys.argv[2])

filename=sys.argv[1]
try:
        with open(filename,"r") as input_text:
            wordcounter=Counter()
            for line in input_text:
                 wordcounter.update(re.findall("\w+",line.lower()))
        if n==0:
            n=len(wordcounter)

        for word, frequency in wordcounter.most_common(n):
            print("%s %d" % (word, frequency))

except IOError:
        sys.exit("Cannot open file: %s"% filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few steps involved in this Problem :

- Clean the Punctuations.
- Sort the Array Based on Frequency.

  ```
  def wordCount(self,nums):
    nums = "Hello, number of transaction which happened, for,"
    nums=nums.lower().translate(None,string.punctuation).split()
    d = {}
    for i in nums:
      if i not in d:
      d[i] = 1
    else:
      d[i] = d[i]+1
   sorted_d = (sorted(d.items(), key = operator.itemgetter(1), reverse = True)

  for key,val in sorted_d:
   print key,val
  ```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I sorted a list of playing cards by most frequent using Counter:

```
counter = Counter([card.value for card in self.cards])
ordered = sorted(self.cards, key=lambda card: -counter[card.value])
```

First I create a counter with all the card values then I sort the cards using the counts in the counter by indexing it.

Answer (score 0):

The previous solutions do not output a dict as you request in your question.

Based on the other answers here and on this stackoverflow post (https://stackoverflow.com/a/613218/13123426), my solution was to use `sorted`, then recreate the dictionary in the sorted order:

```py
from collections import Counter

counter = Counter({'blue': 35, 'red': 252, 'green': 127})

sorted_dict = dict(sorted(counter.items(), 
                          key=lambda item: item[1], 
                          reverse=True))
```