# Python script to find word frequencies of a given document

Tags: python, information-retrieval

I am looking for a simple script that can find frequencies of words for a given document (probably by using portable stemmer).

Is there any library or simple script that does this process?

Comment: google for nltk stemming.  Or search stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[python]+[nltk]+stemmer&submit=search.  Post questions here if you get stuck.

Comment: `collections.Counter(i.lower() for i in re.findall(r'\w+', document))`

Comment: Dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088265/word-frequency-count-using-python

Comment: @JBernardo:  Your solution would count "counting" and "counted" as two separate words.  A library that uses a stemmer would count them together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [nltk](http://www.nltk.org/)

```
import nltk

YOUR_STRING = "Your words"

words = [w for w in YOUR_STRING.split()]
freq_dist = nltk.FreqDist(words)

tokens = freq_dist.keys()

#50 most frequent
most_frequent = tokens[:50]

#50 least frequent
least_frequent = tokens[-50:]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to count words.  Use a `collections.Counter` or a `dict`, depending on what you need.  That part is easy, but if it isn't you can find the answer by searching on SO itself.

I think you also want the Porter Stemmer, which has a Python version at http://tartarus.org/~martin/PorterStemmer/python.txt

Comment: More recent versions of the same stemmer are in nltk.  See http://code.google.com/p/nltk/source/browse/trunk/nltk/nltk/stem/porter.py.