# Sorting a list by frequency of letter in python (decreasing order)

Tags: python, frequency

Like the title says I need to write a function that will sort a list by frequency of letters.  Normally I would supply my code with what I have so far but I have no idea where to get started.  I'm sure its something simple but I just don't know what to do.  I need them sorted in decreasing order, any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

in python 2.7 or higher you can use a counter:
http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

```
>>> mywords = ['red', 'blue', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'blue']
>>> cnt = Counter(mywords)
>>> cnt
Counter({'blue': 3, 'red': 2, 'green': 1})
```

as per [Sorted Word frequency count using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088265/word-frequency-count-using-python)

if you need letters instead of words you can go like this:

```
>>> mywords = ['red', 'blue', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'blue']
>>> myletters=list("".join(mywords))
>>> myletters
['r', 'e', 'd', 'b', 'l', 'u', 'e', 'r', 'e', 'd', 'g', 'r', 'e', 'e', 'n', 'b', 'l', 'u', 'e', 'b', 'l', 'u', 'e']
>>> Counter(myletters)
```

Answer (score 4):

For Python2.7+, use a [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#counter-objects) and its [most_common](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) method:

```
import collections

text='abccccabcbb'
count=collections.Counter(text)

print(count.most_common())
# [('c', 5), ('b', 4), ('a', 2)]

print(''.join(letter*freq for letter,freq in count.most_common()))
# cccccbbbbaa
```

For Python2.6 or lower, you can use the equivalent [Counter recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576611/).