# Python: unique words and their frequency in descending order

Tags: python, cpu-word, unique, frequency

I'm doing a pretty simple homework problem for a Python class involving all sorts of statistics on characters, words and their relative frequencies etc. At the moment I'm trying to analyse a string of text and get a list of every unique word in the text followed by the number of times it is used. I have very limited knowledge of Python (or any language for that matter) as this is an introductory course and so have only come up with the following code:

```py
for k in (""",.’?/!":;«»"""):
    text=text.replace(k,"")
text=text.split()
list1=[(text.count(text[n]),text[n]) for n in range(0,len(text))]
for item in sorted(list1, reverse=True):
    print("%s : %s" % (item[1], item[0]))
```

This unfortunately prints out each individual word of the text (in order of appearance), followed by its frequency n, **n times**. Obviously this is extremely useless, and I'm wondering if I can add in a nifty little bit of code to what I've already written to make each word appear in this list only once, and then eventually in descending order. All the other questions like this I've seen use a lot of code we haven't learned, so I think the answer should be relatively simple.

Comment: How do you think you are asking `sorted(..)` to sort on the "frequencies"?

Comment: Are you already familiar with dictionaries (dict, {})? You could use one to associate words with their appearance count. A Counter, as Martijn suggests, is a specialized kind of dictionary.

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088265/word-frequency-count-using-python

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#counter-objects). You can use it to count your word frequencies, and it'll help you print out the list in sorted order, with the `most_common` method.

(No example code as this is a [homework question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/140890), you'll have to do *some* work yourself).

Comment: Oh, I was already writing example code. But with [[tag:homework]] tag this is probably the best answer.

Comment: Fantastic, I'm not sure if we're supposed to use dictionaries but Counter is certainly what I was looking for. Thank you very much.